# XSLT - Need assistance with multiple conditions

Tags: xml, xslt

I keep on getting an error with my xlst. I want to be able to translate the name of the Location based on the locale for example if the locale = es (spanish) translate "London" to "Londres" and place value in field called LocationField.

This is what I have:

````
    <xsl:call-template name="mapOrcToTalemetryLocationField">
      <xsl:with-param name="code" select="IntegrationLocaleCode"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="location" select="IntegrationFields/IntegrationField[@name='locFlexFields,node,market']"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</LocationField>

   <!--
  Function template.
  -->
  <xsl:template name="mapOrcToTalemetryLocationField">
    <xsl:param name="code"/>
    <xsl:param name="location"/>

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$code = 'en'">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$location = 'Amsterdam'">Amsterdam</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$location = 'Brussels'">Brussels</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$location = 'Copenhagen'">Copenhagen</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$location = 'Dublin'">Dublin</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$location = 'London'">London</xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$code = 'es'">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$location = 'Amsterdam'">Amsterdam Spanish Test</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$location = 'Brussels'">Bruselas</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$location = 'Copenhagen'">Copenhague</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$location = 'Dublin'">Dublin Spanish Test</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$location = 'London'">Londres</xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:when test="$code = 'fr'">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$location = 'Amsterdam'">Amsterdam French Test</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$location = 'Brussels'">Bruxelles</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$location = 'Copenhagen'">Copenhague</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$location = 'Dublin'">Dublin french Test</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$location = 'London'">Londres</xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:when>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>```
````

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tried to implement it.
(3) Desired output.
(4) XSLT processor and its compliance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.

Comment: In addition, if you're getting an error, post the exact error message.